# bugzilla installation using xampp in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, xampp, bugzilla

need to install Bugzilla using XAMPP with Perl on my Windows XP machine. What is the procedure?

I have installed PHP based applications in XAMPP like Joomla, WordPress, etc., but it seems that Bugzilla is Perl based. Its installation guide is saying that I need to install ActivePerl. Do I need to do so since XAMPP comes with Perl addon?

Should I be keeping the source files in htdocs itself or is there any other folder for Perl applications?

I am totally new to Perl and honestly have no idea about it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the installation guide to the letter https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install until it tells you to change the DocumentRoot in your Apache configuration file. DON'T change it to C:/Bugzilla. Instead add the following:

```
Alias /bugzilla C:/Bugzilla
<Directory C:/Bugzilla>
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.0/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

#
# Tell Apache to use Perl to execute .cgi
#
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
</Directory>
```

Then, in the Bugzilla installation folder, find the file called 'params', open it in a decent text editor and change the url base to your server IP (or name) forward slash bugzilla e.g.:

http:// 192.168.7.7/bugzilla/ (without the space between the double slash and IP address)

Make sure you restart apache (using xampp) and run the checksetup.pl script again if you haven't already.

When you've finished following the installation steps, visit the URL you used as the 'url base' above.